# WidgetKit: Recognize home screen widget by id

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I created home screen widget in SwiftUI that displays some data.
I'd like to grant users the ability to add multiple widgets on their screen, where each one of the widgets will have a tag representing the index of the widget. The tag is used to display different data for each widget.

Here's a short example of how each widget should look (a simple TextView representing the tag):

```
Widget 1: "tag = 1"
Widget 2: "tag = 2"
Widget 3: "tag = 3"
```

and so on..

The thing is, I want the tag to be determined by the total available widgets on the screen, so that when I remove, say 2 widgets, then create a new one, the widgets will be updated accordingly

Is that even possible?
I'd like to hear your ideas!

Thank you!

Comment: Your question talks about the widgets having unique ids, but then you talk about wanting to re-use the id of 2. So perhaps you just need to think of these identifiers as tags, rather than as widget ids. How you then map a tag to a widget id is up to you.

Comment: You're right. I suppose tags would be a better way to describe it. The question is how I link a tag to a widget created on the home screen. Any hint you could provide me with will be extremely helpful!

Comment: Ah, so a widget should show the data that belongs to its index position and when the position changes then the data should automatically change accordingly? That means, if two widgets are the same (but presenting different data) and you swap their positions then the big picture still looks the same, right? So I guess the question is, how does a widget find its index position in the overall  layout?

Comment: Yeah, that's spot on. You can think of it as a 'Todo list' where the items keep getting added/deleted. When I add the first widget, Todo #1 will be shown, and so on... when there isn't anything available to show, display 'No items available'. At the moment, I'm storing all of the todos as a list inside UserDefaults, so the only thing that remains is getting the index of each widget so I can map the data